# How to implement a phonetic search using Lucene?

Tags: java, lucene

I want to implement a phonetic search using Lucene 6.1.0., using Soundex or any suitable algorithm for Portuguese. I found many incomplete examples over internet, teaching how to implement a custom tokenizer, analyzer, but it seems that the abstract classes used on those exapmples are not the same in the version 6.1.0. Can anyone point me out where I can find a good documentation an Lucene, not just java docs without any further documentation teaching how to put the things together?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

The [Analyzer documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/core/6_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/Analyzer.html) shows how to create your analyzer.

For phonetic analysis, you should look to the [org.apache.lucene.analysis.phonetic](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_1_0/analyzers-phonetic/index.html) package (You'll need to add "lucene-analyzers-phonetic-6.1.0.jar" to your build path, as well as Apache's "commons-codec-1.10.jar", which you can [get here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/download_codec.cgi)).

Then you can setup your analyzer something like, for instance:

```
Analyzer analyzer = new Analyzer() {
    @Override
    protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String fieldName) {
        Tokenizer tokenizer = new StandardTokenizer();
        TokenStream stream = new DoubleMetaphoneFilter(tokenizer, 6, false);
        return new TokenStreamComponents(tokenizer, stream);
    }
};
```