# How do you use Lucene.Net phonetic search

Tags: c#, lucene.net

The Lucene.Net documentation is extremely lacking - I've been trying to figure out how to make use of the Lucene.Net [phonetic searching functionality](https://lucenenetdocs.azurewebsites.net/api/Lucene.Net.Analysis/Lucene.Net.Analysis.Phonetic.html).

I've mainly been referencing the [lucene.ne git project](https://github.com/apache/lucenenet)'s test case for the PhoneticFilter: https://github.com/apache/lucenenet/blob/master/src/Lucene.Net.Tests.Analysis.Phonetic/TestPhoneticFilter.cs

How I create my index:

```
// add new index entry
Document doc = new Document
{
    new TextField("brand", vehicle.Brand ?? string.Empty, Field.Store.YES),
    new TextField("range", vehicle.Range ?? string.Empty, Field.Store.YES),
    new TextField("model", vehicle.Model ?? string.Empty, Field.Store.YES),
    new TextField("year", vehicle.Year ?? string.Empty, Field.Store.YES),
};

// add entry to index
writer.AddDocument(doc);
```

Next, from the [test case](https://github.com/apache/lucenenet/blob/master/src/Lucene.Net.Tests.Analysis.Phonetic/TestPhoneticFilter.cs), it seems you can add the `PhoneticFilter` to the `Analyzer`:

```
// set up lucene searcher
using DirectoryReader reader = DirectoryReader.Open(Directory);

Analyzer analyzer = Analyzer.NewAnonymous(createComponents: (fieldName, reader) =>
{
    Tokenizer tokenizer = new KeywordTokenizer(reader);
    return new TokenStreamComponents(tokenizer, new PhoneticFilter(tokenizer, new Soundex(), false));
});

IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
int hits_limit = searchModel.Start + searchModel.Qty;
TopDocs topDocs;
Sort sortOrder = null;

BooleanQuery vehicleFilterQuery = new BooleanQuery();

var brandParser = new QueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.LuceneVersion.LUCENE_48, "brand", analyzer);
var brandQuery = ParseQuery(searchModel.SearchTerm, brandParser);
brandQuery.Boost = 4.0f;
vehicleFilterQuery.Add(brandQuery, Occur.SHOULD);

var rangeParser = new QueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.LuceneVersion.LUCENE_48, "range", analyzer);
var rangeQuery = ParseQuery(searchModel.SearchTerm, rangeParser);
rangeQuery.Boost = 3.0f;
vehicleFilterQuery.Add(rangeQuery, Occur.SHOULD);

var modelParser = new QueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.LuceneVersion.LUCENE_48, "model", analyzer);
var modelQuery = ParseQuery(searchModel.SearchTerm, modelParser);
modelQuery.Boost = 2.0f;
vehicleFilterQuery.Add(modelQuery, Occur.SHOULD);

var yearParser = new QueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.LuceneVersion.LUCENE_48, "year", analyzer);
var yearQuery = ParseQuery(searchModel.SearchTerm, yearParser);
yearQuery.Boost = 1.0f;
vehicleFilterQuery.Add(yearQuery, Occur.SHOULD);

topDocs = searcher.Search(vehicleFilterQuery, null, hits_limit, sortOrder ?? Sort.RELEVANCE);
ScoreDoc[] subset = topDocs.ScoreDocs.Skip(searchModel.Start).Take(searchModel.Qty).ToArray();

return MapToModelList(subset, searcher);
```

After implementing this in order to test, I search with `Audee`, expecting to get a bunch of `Audi` results, but while the regular (correctly spelled) search works, the phonetic search seems to have no impact.

I've tried the `Metaphone()`, `DoubleMetaphone()`, `Soundex()`, `RefinedSoundex()`, `Caverphone1()` and `Caverphone2()` encoders

> Metaphone https://lucenenetdocs.azurewebsites.net/api/Lucene.Net.Analysis/Lucene.Net.Analysis.Phonetic.Language.Metaphone.html
>
> DoubleMetaphone https://lucenenetdocs.azurewebsites.net/api/Lucene.Net.Analysis/Lucene.Net.Analysis.Phonetic.Language.DoubleMetaphone.html
>
> Soundex https://lucenenetdocs.azurewebsites.net/api/Lucene.Net.Analysis/Lucene.Net.Analysis.Phonetic.Language.Soundex.html
>
> RefinedSoundex https://lucenenetdocs.azurewebsites.net/api/Lucene.Net.Analysis/Lucene.Net.Analysis.Phonetic.Language.RefinedSoundex.html
>
> Caverphone1 https://lucenenetdocs.azurewebsites.net/api/Lucene.Net.Analysis/Lucene.Net.Analysis.Phonetic.Language.Caverphone1.html
>
> Caverphone2 https://lucenenetdocs.azurewebsites.net/api/Lucene.Net.Analysis/Lucene.Net.Analysis.Phonetic.Language.Caverphone2.html

Answer (score 2):

There is a specialized [`DoubleMetaphoneFilter`](https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/4.8.0-beta00013/api/analysis-phonetic/Lucene.Net.Analysis.Phonetic.DoubleMetaphoneFilter.html) designed for basic phonetic matches. You only need to use the `PhoneticFilter` if you need explicit control over the phonetic algorithm being used.

Here is an example (based on [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38600668)):

```
// Ensures index backward compatibility
const LuceneVersion AppLuceneVersion = LuceneVersion.LUCENE_48;

[Test]
public void DoubleMetaphoneExample()
{
    // Create a directory
    var directory = new RAMDirectory();

    // Create a phonetic analyzer
    var analyzer = Analyzer.NewAnonymous(createComponents: (fieldName, reader) => {
        var tokenizer = new KeywordTokenizer(input: reader);
        var stream = new DoubleMetaphoneFilter(input: tokenizer, maxCodeLength: 8, inject: false);
        return new TokenStreamComponents(tokenizer, stream);
    });

    // Create an index writer
    var indexConfig = new IndexWriterConfig(AppLuceneVersion, analyzer);
    using (var writer = new IndexWriter(directory, indexConfig))
    {
        // Add documents
        foreach (var vehicle in Vehicles)
        {
            // add new index entry
            Document doc = new Document
            {
                new TextField("brand", vehicle.Brand ?? string.Empty, Field.Store.YES),
                new TextField("range", vehicle.Range ?? string.Empty, Field.Store.YES),
                new TextField("model", vehicle.Model ?? string.Empty, Field.Store.YES),
                new TextField("year", vehicle.Year ?? string.Empty, Field.Store.YES),
            };

            // add entry to index
            writer.AddDocument(doc);
        }
    }
    // Done indexing

    // Begin Search

    var searchModel = new { SearchTerm = "audee" };

    // Open an IndexReader
    using var reader = DirectoryReader.Open(directory);

    IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
    int hits_limit = 5;
    TopDocs topDocs;
    Sort sortOrder = null;

    BooleanQuery vehicleFilterQuery = new BooleanQuery();

    var brandParser = new QueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.LuceneVersion.LUCENE_48, "brand", analyzer);
    var brandQuery = ParseQuery(searchModel.SearchTerm, brandParser);
    brandQuery.Boost = 4.0f;
    vehicleFilterQuery.Add(brandQuery, Occur.SHOULD);

    var rangeParser = new QueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.LuceneVersion.LUCENE_48, "range", analyzer);
    var rangeQuery = ParseQuery(searchModel.SearchTerm, rangeParser);
    rangeQuery.Boost = 3.0f;
    vehicleFilterQuery.Add(rangeQuery, Occur.SHOULD);

    var modelParser = new QueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.LuceneVersion.LUCENE_48, "model", analyzer);
    var modelQuery = ParseQuery(searchModel.SearchTerm, modelParser);
    modelQuery.Boost = 2.0f;
    vehicleFilterQuery.Add(modelQuery, Occur.SHOULD);

    var yearParser = new QueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.LuceneVersion.LUCENE_48, "year", analyzer);
    var yearQuery = ParseQuery(searchModel.SearchTerm, yearParser);
    yearQuery.Boost = 1.0f;
    vehicleFilterQuery.Add(yearQuery, Occur.SHOULD);

    topDocs = searcher.Search(vehicleFilterQuery, null, hits_limit, sortOrder ?? Sort.RELEVANCE);

    // topDocs.ScoreDocs contains

    // doc = 2
    // doc = 3
    // doc = 4
    // doc = 7
}

private static Search.Query ParseQuery(string searchTerm, QueryParser queryParser)
{
    return queryParser.Parse(searchTerm);
}

private static Vehicle[] Vehicles = new Vehicle[] {
    new Vehicle { Brand = "Ford", Model = "Taurus", Year = "1986" },
    new Vehicle { Brand = "Ford", Model = "Fiesta", Year = "1990" },
    new Vehicle { Brand = "Audi", Model = "A4 45", Year = "2021" },
    new Vehicle { Brand = "Audi", Model = "Q3 45 S", Year = "2021" },
    new Vehicle { Brand = "Audie", Model = "Q3 45 S", Year = "2021" },
    new Vehicle { Brand = "Toyota", Model = "Corolla", Year = "2010" },
    new Vehicle { Brand = "Toyota", Model = "Hilux", Year = "2015" },
    new Vehicle { Brand = "Audi", Model = "A4", Year = "2017" },
};

public class Vehicle
{
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string Range { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `PhoneticFilter` to pick an algorithm. I tried your example with `DoubleMetaphone` (both with and without setting `MaxCodeLen`) and it worked fine.

```
var stream = new PhoneticFilter(
    input: tokenizer,
    encoder: new DoubleMetaphone() { MaxCodeLen = 8 },
    inject: false);
```

There is some general information about [phonetic algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonetic_algorithm) on Wikipedia. In most cases, Double Metaphone is the best choice for the English language.